# PHP video file not in $FILES array

Tags: php, forms, file, video, upload

I have written a file upload script in PHP. Initially I just have an html form and am telling the page just to do phpinfo();exit; on POST. This is my html form:

```
<form action="/admin/files.htm" method="POST" class="styled" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Upload File</label>
<input type="file" id="" name="file">
<input type="submit" value="Upload" id="" name="submit">
</form>
```

When I upload any file except for video it shows up in the $_FILES array fine. However any video file - the $FILES array just isn't there!

I have already checked PHP ini and post_max_size and upload_max_filesize are both set to 200M.

Any ideas?

Comment: can you post some code? and copy and paste the relevant sections from the php.ini file?

Comment: Did you try to rename file to other extension?Are you sure you don't have directive Limit POST with mime type/content type in httpd.conf ?

Comment: In the php page called when the form is submitted try to print $_FILES array: print_r($_FILES) You can see informations on the uploaded file: especially check the error fields of this array and post here the output

Comment: Posting the relevant part of your PHP script would help the community assist you.

Answer (score 0):

check may be restricted by any security tool like [suhosin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suhosin)

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would rename a video file to have a .txt extension and upload that. If it goes through then you know you have something filtering your filetypes. Obviously make sure the file size is less than 200MB. Make it like 5mb or something.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this exact problem - all files upload fine except for videos. I solved it by setting the following in php.ini or as the script executes:

```
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '100M');
ini_set('post_max_size', '100M');
ini_set('max_input_time', 600);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 600);
```